# NUnit3 test assemblies location in my .exe file instead of .dlls

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I did some research and I always found that the tests are located in some dll. However in my project there are no .dlls created and the tests are located in the .exe file.

Do I have to set some specific parameters?

This is the log from vsts after I pointed the path for test assemblies to the exe. Before I pointed it to **\*.test*.dll but it could never find any tests. When running the tests or build locally there is also never a test dll created.

```
2017-08-15T08:55:15.1386003Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2017-08-15T08:55:15.4276084Z Information: NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0: Test execution started
2017-08-15T08:55:15.4276084Z 
2017-08-15T08:55:15.4276084Z Information: Running all tests in d:\a\1\s\Workshop\Workshop\bin\Release\Workshop.exe
2017-08-15T08:55:15.4286085Z 
2017-08-15T08:55:16.8199687Z Information: NUnit3TestExecutor converted 1 of 1 NUnit test cases
2017-08-15T08:55:16.8199687Z 
2017-08-15T08:55:16.9559755Z Information: NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0: Test execution complete
2017-08-15T08:55:16.9559755Z 
2017-08-15T08:55:17.2181003Z Passed   TwoIntegers_Add_Sum
```

How do I make the tests show up as .dlls instead of being inside the .exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your example shows, NUnit as well as VS Test Explorer are very happy to have tests in an `.exe` along with the production code. Most people prefer to have the tests separate from the production code, which is distributed to users, so they create a separate project to contain them.

So, your answer is that there is no way to make the tests "show up" as a `.dll` if they are actually in the `.exe`. OTOH, assuming you are the developer of the application, you can create a separate project, which creates a class library, and move the tests into that project.

Comment: I am feeling dumb. This makes total sense! Thank you!